# Why do I get these warnings with 14pt scrartcl

Tags: fontsize, warnings

This is what my file looks like:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{scrartcl} 
\begin{document}
\Huge Hi
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

```
Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <35.83> not available(Font) size <24.88> substituted
Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 10.95pt have occurred.
```

How should I get rid of these warnings?
I thought scrartcl was supposed to support the 14pt option?
*updates after comments*
The warnings vanish when I remove `\Huge`.

Comment: Because the fontsetup is in many cases quantified. Try adding the `anyfontsize` package and perhaps `lmodern` if you're using `miktex` (`miktex` usually do not add `cm-super` and thus seem to not use Type 1 versions of the CM font.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; you may want also `\usepackage{lmodern}`. You might also try instead with the `fix-cm` package.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{extsizes}` to the preamble does solve the errors you just mentioned, but I don't know if it is a good solution, as it doesn't support all sizes.

Comment: @daleif I tried lmodern It got rid of the warning but changed all the products in my displaymath to their textstyle versions for some reason (is there a workaround for that?)
anyfontsize works perfectly.
It is not needed without the "\Huge" though, any idea why? I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Fictional, do you mind updating your question to show that?

Comment: @Fictional: show the products, I'd like to see the rest of your setup

Comment: Hang on, I think my comment bout lmodern might not be correct. Let me test it.
Indeed I was confused. I am sorry. lmodern works perfectly as well.
I have to say: I still do not understand why it is needed though.

Comment: There is still a difference between displaystyle and textstyle, but the font difference decreased. Perhaps the only available font sizes where further apart in size. If so, it would explain why the difference decreased when I used lmodern. Same thing happened with anyfontsize btw. I'll use lmodern from now on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no warning if I say

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[14pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\Huge Hi
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\Huge Hi
\end{document}
```

There's no warning either with

```
\documentclass[14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\Huge Hi
\end{document}
```

The two solution are a bit different, though: in the first one the original (but fully scalable) Computer Modern fonts are used; in the latter we use the Latin Modern fonts, that are similar but not identical.

---

The problem is that with the original LaTeX setup, the Computer Modern fonts are available only at some sizes (this has to do with the fact that at LaTeX2e release time Type1 fonts were not as widespread as today). The `fix-cm` package changes the situation by allowing scaling to every size. In case the OT1 (default) font encoding is used, the package should be loaded before `\documentclass`.

The Latin Modern fonts have allowed scaling since their release.

Comment: Why don't you use `fontenc` -- It fixes the issue too.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It does, but, depending on the OP's setup, it might introduce other issues (missing CM-Super fonts, for instance). In any case, also the original EC fonts are in available in a limited series of sizes.